# Alternatives to sending swiftc AST output to stderr

Tags: swift, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using the swiftc compiler to generate abstract syntax trees and I'm looking for an alternative to the default `-dump-ast` behavior of sending all the output to stderr. There's an `-output-file-map` option, but I can't find any documentation on it and a search of the github repository didn't reveal anything. The `-o` option doesn't appear to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to output AST into the file:

`xcrun swiftc -frontend -emit-syntax #{file} > #{output}`

e.g. `xcrun swiftc -frontend -emit-syntax Test.swift > Test_ast.json`

It'll fill up `Test_ast.json` with a minified JSON representation of an AST.

you could also use python's ability to beautify it:

`xcrun swiftc -frontend -emit-syntax Test.swift | python -m json.tool > Test_ast.json`

but it'll increase the file size

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative 1

`swiftc -dump-ast foo.swift [...] -o foo.ast` will dump the AST to the file foo.ast.

## Alternative 2

`swiftc -dump-ast -output-file-map=outputFileMap.json *.swift [...]`, given an outputFileMap.json file that contains entries in the form "ast-dump": "foo.ast", will dump the ASTs of the input files to their respective output files in the file map.

Related pull request could be found [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/20392) and discussion could be found [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/error-when-dumping-the-ast-for-hundreds-of-files/17578/11).

Comment: can u help with command linking multiple files via command line, Thanks